A continuous differential equation with no solution
I am studying the following counterexample.

But I don't understand where the fact that space is infinite dimensional is used. What fails in an infinite dimensional space?

They're using the fact that $\forall n,\forall t\ge 0, u_n(t)\ge t^2/4$ is inconsistent with $\forall t, \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n(t)=0$, which surely doesn't make sense if $u$ does not take values in the specific space they've chosen. It might not have been in their interest to explain the difference between this case and the case of a function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$.
